# What is the poolSize: number, in mongo db atlas?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

What does it mean if i set the poolSize to "poolSize: 10" ?
Let's say i get 1 000 requests that does 1 find() each, how many connections would that result in? And i use Node Js as the driver.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on where you are creating the pool. If you create inside the route that is a bad practice. If you create the connection pool outside the route defintion, the connection will be reused for all the incoming requests.

This [article](https://blog.mlab.com/2013/11/deep-dive-into-connection-pooling/) explains it very nicely.

Comment: Yeah okey i see, i have "pool outside the route defintion", so lets say i get 1 000 requests, how many connections would that result in? I just trying to estimate which tier im going to need for mongo db atlas. And i want to configure the backend so i get as small of amount of connections as possible, so i can use a lower tier for mongo db.

Comment: I would say best way to test this will to run db.runCommand( { "connPoolStats" : 1 } ) commNd while running your requests and see how many connection